# Create nested list from os walk in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a nested list which will look like

`[['a','b'],['c','d']]`

Code-

```
gridList = []
file = []

    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            file.append(name)
            file.append(path)
gridList.append(file)
print(gridList)
```

It produces the following list which is not correct.

`[['a','b','c','d']]`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gridList.append(file)` is not properly indented. You also aren't clearing `file` for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just change the line of `append` in your code:

```
for name in files:
    file.append([name,path])
```